# Unset many array

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I need help with my code. To unset xfer array from array below:

```
    if($_SESSION["s"]["user"]["typ"] == 'admin') {
    $form["tabs"]['dns_soa'] = array (
        'title'     => "DNS Zone",
        'width'     => 100,
        'template'  => "templates/dns_soa_edit.htm",
        'fields'    => array (
        ##################################
        # Begin Datatable fields
        ##################################

        'xfer' => array (
            'datatype'  => 'VARCHAR',
            'formtype'  => 'TEXT',
            'default'   => '',
            'value'     => '',
            'width'     => '30',
            'maxlength' => '255'
        ),

        'update_acl' => array (
            'datatype'  => 'VARCHAR',
            'formtype'  => 'TEXT',
            'default'   => '',
            'value'     => '',
            'width'     => '30',
            'maxlength' => '255'
        ),

        'active' => array (
            'datatype'  => 'VARCHAR',
            'formtype'  => 'CHECKBOX',
            'default'   => 'Y',
            'value'     => array(0 => 'N',1 => 'Y')
        ),
        ##################################
        # ENDE Datatable fields
        ##################################
        )
    );
    }
```

I just:

```
unset($form["tabs"]['dns_soa']['fields']['xfer']);
```

and to unset all 3 I do this. UPDATE - I have many array in 'fields' actually but I just provide 3:

```
unset($form["tabs"]['dns_soa']['fields']['xfer']);
unset($form["tabs"]['dns_soa']['fields']['update_acl']);
unset($form["tabs"]['dns_soa']['fields']['active']);
```

Is there anyway I could unset many array without coding 
`unset($form["tabs"]['dns_soa']['fields']array name here);` many times? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE - My apologies I should provide more information. How do you disable 2 out of 3 array? For example just disable ['xfer'] and ['active']?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just say:

```
// to unset the parent "fields" array, which includes xfer, update_acl and active
unset($form["tabs"]['dns_soa']['fields']);
```

or

```
// just to reset the fields array
$form["tabs"]['dns_soa']['fields'] = array();
```

UPDATE:

To unset only a particular subset of the keys without repeating `unset` many times in the code, I would do a loop:

```
foreach (array('xfer', 'active') as $field) {
  unset($form["tabs"]['dns_soa']['fields'][$field]);
}
```

Comment: My apologies I should provide more information. How do you disable 2 out of 3 array? For example just disable ['xfer'] and ['active']?

Comment: aahh foreach. I already learned this in my class. Thank you very much sir/madam. You a time saver :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to unset all the subarray in `fields`, you can use:

```
unset($form["tabs"]['dns_soa']['fields']);
```

**Edit**: In this case the best you can do is to use a for or foreach.

Comment: My apologies I should provide more information. How do you disable 2 out of 3 array? For example just disable ['xfer'] and ['active']?

Answer (score 1):

If it's something you plan on using frequently, you could just create a function to help shorthand it:

```
<?php
function unset_array($keys, &$arr) {
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}

unset_array(array('xfer', 'active'), $arr['tabs']['dns_soa']);
?>
```